# More Efficient 3-Period Rolling Average Calculation

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of numeric answers to survey questions. The goal is to call a stored procedure, with a parameter for PeriodType ("Quarter", "Month", or "Year") that returns this output:

```
Year    Period    Score    WeightedAverage
2019    1         85.7     85.7
2019    2         87.6     85.9
2019    3         90.5     88.6
...    ...        ....     ....
```

Couple of notes:

- **WeightedAverage should be a 3-period rolling average, but NOT the average of the current and two previous averages.** It should take into account all individual answers so that a period with 1000 answers has a larger effect than a period with 50 answers. Using windowed functions like LEAD/LAG or AVG OVER() do not seem to be the answer.
- Setup is depicted below, and the #answers table has roughly 302,000 rows in it. The final query itself takes 35 seconds. Would like this optimized as best as possible.
- The table scan to get **#answers [c]** creates an index spool (eager) and then a table spool (lazy) in the execution plan. Row estimate 34; execution estimate 2,705; actual rows 160,773,768; actual executions 33,037 (yikes). There has to be a faster way that my inferior brain can't solve.
- Running SQL Server 2017 Enterprise, but compatibility level 100 (SQL 2008)

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #answers (   ResponseID int,   QuestionID int,   Answer float,   CompletedDate datetime,   dateID int    )  
-- code to insert 302,000 answers would go here  
-- create a table of all date possibilities (there are no gaps), with an identity  for each  

SELECT id = identity(int, 1, 1), [year] = DATEPART(year, CompletedDate), period = CASE @PeriodType WHEN 'Month' THEN DATEPART(month, CompletedDate) WHEN 'Quarter' THEN DATEPART(quarter, CompletedDate) ELSE NULL END  
INTO #dates FROM #answers  
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, CompletedDate), CASE @PeriodType WHEN 'Month' THEN DATEPART(month, CompletedDate) WHEN 'Quarter' THEN DATEPART(quarter, CompletedDate) ELSE NULL END  
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, CompletedDate), CASE @PeriodType WHEN 'Month' THEN DATEPART(month, CompletedDate) WHEN 'Quarter' THEN DATEPART(quarter, CompletedDate) ELSE NULL END

-- update the answers table with the assigned dateID identity  
UPDATE a SET dateID = b.id  
FROM #answers a  
INNER JOIN #dates b ON DATEPART(year, a.CompletedDate) = b.[year] AND ((CASE @PeriodType WHEN 'Month' THEN DATEPART(month, a.CompletedDate) WHEN 'Quarter' THEN DATEPART(quarter, a.CompletedDate) ELSE NULL END) = b.period OR (b.period IS NULL AND @PeriodType NOT IN ('Month', 'Quarter')))

-- join the answers to themselves based on (dateID - 2) for 3-period score  
SELECT #dates.[year], #dates.[period], internal.score, internal.weightedaverage  
FROM #dates  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (  
    SELECT b.[year], b.period, score = CAST(10 * AVG(a.Answer) AS decimal(10, 1)), weightedaverage = CAST(10 * AVG(c.Answer) AS decimal(10, 1))  
    FROM #answers a  
    INNER JOIN #dates b ON a.dateID = b.id  
    INNER JOIN #answers c ON c.dateID > a.dateID - 2 AND c.dateID <= a.dateID
    GROUP BY b.[year], b.period  
) internal ON #dates.[year] = internal.[year] AND #dates.[period] = internal.[period]  
ORDER BY #dates.[year], #dates.[period]
```

Apologies for the formatting, I don't see how to indent and clean up how this t-sql is displayed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The editing problem was a tricky one.  You apparently can't transition directly from a list to a code snippet.